# Is WP-CLI incompatible with Bitnami's Wordpress install on AWS Lightsail?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, bitnami, wp-cli, amazon-lightsail

Using a new instance of Wordpress on Ubuntu, I installed `wp-cli` via [these instructions](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/). I tried [downloading the .phar package, chmodding it, etc](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/#recommended-installation).I also tried [installing a .deb package](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/#installing-via-deb-package). In both cases I get the same errors when running `wp plugin update --all --debug`:

```
Debug (bootstrap): No readable global config found (0.057s)
Debug (bootstrap): No project config found (0.057s)
Debug (bootstrap): argv: /usr/local/bin/wp plugin update --all --debug (0.057s)
Debug (bootstrap): ABSPATH defined: /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/ (0.058s)
Debug (bootstrap): Begin WordPress load (0.058s)
Debug (bootstrap): wp-config.php path: /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php (0.058s)
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1070) : eval()'d code on line 90
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1070) : eval()'d code on line 91
Debug (bootstrap): Loaded WordPress (0.188s)
Debug (bootstrap): Running command: plugin update (0.188s)
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.4.0.zip...
Using cached file '/home/bitnami/.wp-cli/cache/plugin/akismet-4.0.zip'...
Unpacking the update...
Warning: Could not create directory.
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/all-in-one-wp-migration.6.58.zip...
Using cached file '/home/bitnami/.wp-cli/cache/plugin/all-in-one-wp-migration-6.58.zip'...
Unpacking the update...
Warning: Could not create directory.
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/all-in-one-seo-pack.2.4.2.zip...
Using cached file '/home/bitnami/.wp-cli/cache/plugin/all-in-one-seo-pack-2.4.2.zip'...
Unpacking the update...
Warning: Could not create directory.
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/google-analytics-for-wordpress.6.2.4.zip...
Using cached file '/home/bitnami/.wp-cli/cache/plugin/google-analytics-for-wordpress-6.2.4.zip'...
Unpacking the update...
Warning: Could not create directory.
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.5.4.zip...
Using cached file '/home/bitnami/.wp-cli/cache/plugin/jetpack-5.4.zip'...
Unpacking the update...
Warning: Could not create directory.
+--------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| name                           | old_version | new_version | status |
+--------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| akismet                        | 3.3.4       | 4.0         | Error  |
| all-in-one-wp-migration        | 6.55        | 6.58        | Error  |
| all-in-one-seo-pack            | 2.3.15      | 2.4.2       | Error  |
| google-analytics-for-wordpress | 6.2.0       | 6.2.4       | Error  |
| jetpack                        | 5.2.1       | 5.4         | Error  |
+--------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
Success: Plugins already updated.
```

I've run through the [list of support options](http://wp-cli.org/#support) and I'm still unable to get wp-cli to work properly on AWS Lightsail, aka Bitnami. Looking at the [github](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sort%3Aupdated-desc%20org%3Awp-cli%20is%3Aissue) and [wordpress.org forums](https://wordpress.org/support/topic-tag/wp-cli/), I see that lots of users have had some or all of the above errors. I tried all the suggested work-arounds:

- `wp-config.php`: Wrap the ABSPATH line in a conditional.
- `wp-config.php`: Move the `add_filter()` call into a MU plugin.
- Several `chmod` and `chown` changes.

Some of these did make their respective errors go away, but `wp` still can't update plugins, etc.

Do I need to create the missing files identified in the PHP debug output?

Should I just not use AWS Lightsail/Bitnami? I really need `wp-cli`, so I'm willing to just move to ec2 or whatever else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitnami Developer here.

Could you try running the commands as the user `daemon`?

```
 sudo su -s /bin/bash daemon
```

This is the user that has permission to write on the server

Comment: That was the solution. Thank you! Here is exactly what I had to do, in order:

`sudo su -s /bin/bash daemon

export PATH=/opt/bitnami/varnish/bin:/opt/bitnami/sqlite/bin:/opt/bitnami/php/bin:/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

cd /home/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs

wp plugin update --all --debug
...
Success: Updated 5 of 5 plugins.
`

Comment: Also see my better-formatted version of my use of your solution, below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I see two different issues there.

1. You're using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in your `wp-config.php` file,
   which is not set while WP-CLI is being run. As WP-CLI is run as a
   command-line tool, some of the web-only PHP constants/variables are
   not set. You'll need to either set these manually or provide a
   conditional override.
2. WordPress itself cannot create a directory in which to unpack the
   downloaded plugin archive files. This might be due to 1. above (as
   WordPress might be looking in the wrong location), or it might be an
   unrelated issue, like running WP-CLI with a different user that does
   not have the required permissions.

Both issues are not directly caused by WP-CLI, but rather the result of the particular setup of your WordPress installation.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using the `wp-config.php` file provided with the Bitnami installation of Wordpress. Can I simply download or create a version of this file that will be compatible with WP-CLI?

Comment: I don't know what that file includes. I have to assume they have some special configuration in there, so just downloading a standard config file will probably break stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Javier Salmeron! Here is exactly what I had to do, in order:

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash daemon

export PATH=/opt/bitnami/varnish/bin:/opt/bitnami/sqlite/bin:/opt/bitnami/php/bin:/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

cd /home/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
```

Now it worked because the following was true:

1. I was user `daemon`.
2. My `$PATH` was able to find `/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php`.
3. I was in the correct directory: `/home/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs`

The following command ran successfully: `wp plugin update --all --debug`

```
Debug (bootstrap): No readable global config found (0.058s)
Debug (bootstrap): No project config found (0.059s)
Debug (bootstrap): argv: /usr/local/bin/wp plugin update --all --debug (0.059s)
Debug (bootstrap): ABSPATH defined: /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/ (0.059s)
Debug (bootstrap): Begin WordPress load (0.061s)
Debug (bootstrap): wp-config.php path: /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php (0.061s)
Debug (bootstrap): Loaded WordPress (0.678s)
Debug (bootstrap): Running command: plugin update (0.679s)
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/WP_CLI/FileCache.php on line 265
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/WP_CLI/FileCache.php on line 265
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.4.0.zip...
Unpacking the update...
Installing the latest version...
Removing the old version of the plugin...
Plugin updated successfully.
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/all-in-one-wp-migration.6.59.zip...
Unpacking the update...
Installing the latest version...
Removing the old version of the plugin...
Plugin updated successfully.
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/all-in-one-seo-pack.2.4.2.zip...
Unpacking the update...
Installing the latest version...
Removing the old version of the plugin...
Plugin updated successfully.
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/google-analytics-for-wordpress.6.2.4.zip...
Unpacking the update...
Installing the latest version...
Removing the old version of the plugin...
Plugin updated successfully.
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.5.4.zip...
Unpacking the update...
Installing the latest version...
Removing the old version of the plugin...
Plugin updated successfully.
+--------------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| name                           | old_version | new_version | status  |
+--------------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| akismet                        | 3.3.4       | 4.0         | Updated |
| all-in-one-wp-migration        | 6.55        | 6.59        | Updated |
| all-in-one-seo-pack            | 2.3.15      | 2.4.2       | Updated |
| google-analytics-for-wordpress | 6.2.0       | 6.2.4       | Updated |
| jetpack                        | 5.2.1       | 5.4         | Updated |
+--------------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
Success: Updated 5 of 5 plugins.
```